# polytiles.py not showing large areas of water with osm carto style

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, style, mapnik

I've used polytiles.py with the old XML OSM style to generate tiles from the GB pbf and it worked fine. However, when I import the PBF into the db with the openstreetmap-carto style and use polytiles.py again, the tiles are created as before but without any large areas of water. e.g. the tile should look like:

[image]

but using carto and polytiles.py it looks like this:

[image]

I've run get-shapefiles.sh, carto is installed via 'npm install carto' and 'apt-get install node-carto' and I was wondering what steps I might have missed?

Answer (score 1):

> what steps I might have missed?

[osm2pgsql](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql)? You don't mention at all what you use to create your database...

These lakes are almost certainly large OSM multipolygon relations. Quite a lot of software does not properly process them.

Comment: I used osm2pgsql with the default osm.xml style and it's fine. I used the master version of openstreetmap-carto and it did the above. I used the 2.39.0 release and it was even worse. A blue tint over the whole map